# C# Application can't connect to mirroring SQL Server after manually failover

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-mirroring

I set up mirroring databases (computer name: SQL-Prim, SQL-Mirr, domain name: sql-1.ooo.org, sql-2.ooo.org).
I don't have AD, and I configure them with public IP addresses and domain names.
I wrote a C# application to test the failover behavior.
The connection string is like this:

```
data source=sql-1.ooo.org;Failover Partner=sql-2.ooo.org;initial catalog=TestDB;User Id={0};Password={1};App=EntityFramework
```

The C# application is to update data continuously:

```
while (true)
{
  try
  {
    using (TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
    {
      //update data
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //log error
  }
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //sleep for a while
}
```

At beginning, the application connects to SQL-Prim and runs well.
When I failover manually from SQL-Prim to SQL-Mirr, the application throws exceptions:

```
"The underlying provider failed on Open."
```

If I restart the application, it connects to SQL-Mirror and runs well. Then, I failover again manually from SQL-Mirr to SQL-Prim. The application keeps running well. If I failover manually from SQL-Prim to SQL-Mirr, the application throws the same exceptions again.

I try to add the IP address of SQL-Mirr to "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host" on the test application's computer.
The application runs well. I can failover the 2 DBs arbitrarily without any error.

I'm confused with this problem.
Is there any idea to avoid changing the host file?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable  "allow Remote clients" in DTC config.